# Is it right to copy the old R version packages to the new folder that contains the packages of the new version?

Tags: r, package

I installed the latest version of r 3.5.0 and copied all the packages, from my old version 3.4.3, and pasted them to the current version folder 3.5
I think this is not a good way to copy and paste the packages because RStudio asks me to reinstall the package that I call. For example, it gives me this error when I install zoo:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘zoo’:
package ‘zoo’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it 
needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

What should I do to copy them the right way?

Comment: have you tried `update.packages(check.built=TRUE,ask=FALSE)` ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @BrianStamper Windows

Comment: but it works so well with @BenBolker suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK. note it should be `checkBuilt` as in @BrianStamper's answer (but you must have figured that out)

Comment: I did it with `check.built` and it works -- I think it's the same.

Comment: huh. Maybe you got lucky and most of your packages had new versions that would be installed?  I think `check.built` probably got ignored ...

Comment: Agreed about it being ignored, there is a `...` in the function signature which probably took the `check.built = TRUE` and did nothing with it. Since your old version was `3.4.3` if your packages were up to date with that you should be fine, or you could run the update again with `checkBuilt = TRUE`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed now. I will do it with `checkBuilt = TRUE`

Answer (score 13):

It is much safer to re-build packages for the newer version of R rather than coping them.

The easiest way to re-build all the packages,  would be to save the list of packages in the old version of R in the file, then load it into the new version of R and install them:

```
# In old version of R:
ip <- installed.packages()[,1]
write(ip,"rpackages_in_3.4.3.txt")
q()

# In new version of R:
ip_3.4.3 <- readLines("rpackages_in_3.4.3.txt")
setRepositories(graphics=FALSE, ind=1:6)
install.packages(ip_3.4.3)
```

There is also package **installr** that might be useful for this purpose:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/installr.pdf

Comment: Great help. Correction for last line: install.packages(ip_3.4.3)

Answer (score 8):

EDIT 2024: Note that this has not been true since R 4.2.0. The link to the FAQ below leads to the current correct recommendation as of this time of writing.

---

For Windows at least, and perhaps others, what you have done plus what @Ben Bolker suggests is exactly what the manual says most people should do:

> For most people the best thing to do is to [...] copy any installed packages to the library folder in the new installation, run update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE) in the new R and then delete anything left of the old installation.

From: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What_0027s-the-best-way-to-upgrade_003f

However, they also qualify that by saying it is "a matter of taste", so if you find another method that works for you go with that, I just wanted to point out the method you tried is valid and even suggested by the documentation.

UPDATE: I just had R updated on my own system and since I use a fixed location for my packages (i.e. no version number in the path) I didn't even copy them from one place to another, I only did the `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` part and it works fine.

Comment: For upgrades that go from R 4.1 to R 4.2, I believe this solution has limitations. The current R for Windows FAQ says "A previously recommended option was to copy any installed packages to the library folder in the new installation, run update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE) in the new R and then delete anything left of the old installation...This would often work, but not e.g. when upgrading from R 4.1 to R 4.2, in that case one could do this only for packages without native code/DLLs. "