# Change of location of R libraries throws error

Tags: r, package, migration, knitr

I have an issue with the library path of R. Maybe the answer is out there already, but I was not able to find it. I am using R together with RStudio Version 1.1.456. All my additional libraries used to be in a directory `dir1 <- \\SHARE\TOOLS_OLD$\R-3.5.1` which I append with `.libPaths(dir1)`. In this setup, everything works as expected.

The problem occured after I copied all the libraries in directory `\\SHARE\TOOLS_OLD$\R-3.5.1` to a new location `\\NAS\TOOLSNEW$\R-3.5.1`. I did not update the R version and I want to keep all the package versions the same such that I have exactly the same setup as before. That is why I did not reinstall the packages in the new location.

When I open a new R session and run the three lines of code

```
dir2 <-  \\NAS\TOOLSNEW$\R-3.5.1
.libPaths(dir2)
.libPaths()
```

I get the correct output of `.libPaths()`

```
[1] "\\\\NAS/TOOLSNEW$/R-3.5.1" "C:/Apps/R-3.5.1/library"
```

but R also throws an error:

```
Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
no package 'knitr' was found
```

Apparently some packages remember the original location where they were installed. Is there a way to copy packages to a new location without reinstalling them? If that is not possible, is there an easy (i.e. non-manual) way to reinstall my package tree without upgrading any of the packages (including the dependencies) i.e. defining the version of each package?

Thanks for your help!

PS: Here is my session info, just in case.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    
LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can have many causes, e.g. there might be some dependencies which are lost by copying the package folder or that the registry entries don't match anymore, but I'm guessing here. When you copy packages from older versions you have to run `update.packages` (but this might update any package to the currently available version, which you don't want). Check out the [R-FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What_0027s-the-best-way-to-upgrade_003f) and this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134848/r-is-it-right-to-copy-the-old-r-version-packages-to-the-new-folder-that-contai/50135213).

You can install packages of a certain version with the `devtools` package.

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)

install_version(somePackage, version = neededVersion)
```

How I did it was I created a `data.frame` of all the required packages with the corresponding version number, like

```
> requiredPkgs

                   Package              Version 
condformat         "condformat"         "0.9.0" 
DT                 "DT"                 "0.17"  
formattable        "formattable"        "0.2.1" 
ggplot2            "ggplot2"            "3.3.3" 
ggthemes           "ggthemes"           "4.2.4" 
htmlTable          "htmlTable"          "2.1.0"
```

and then installed them in a loop

```
for(iPkg in requiredPkgs) {
  install_version(iPkg[1], version = iPkg[2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that I could do that manually. The problem is that there are quite a lot of packages which I would have to install in this manner so I was wondering if there is a better solution. Furthermore, I don't know why this problem shows up in the first place.